# Error: Running programs "" with an unhandled exception

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I am getting the following error:

```
error: Running program '/builds/infra/gcp/gke' failed with an unhandled exception:
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
iam.ts(12,34): error TS2694: Namespace '"/builds/infra/gcp/gke/node_modules/@pulumi/gcp/index"' has no exported member 'serviceAccount'.
iam.ts(20,28): error TS2339: Property 'serviceAccount' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/builds/infra/gcp/gke/node_modules/@pulumi/gcp/index")'.
```

This is also the code for sa:

```
export class GServiceAccount extends pulumi.ComponentResource {
    public readonly account: gcp.serviceAccount.Account;

    constructor(
        name: string,
        args: GServiceAccountArgs,
        opts?: pulumi.ResourceOptions
    ) {
        super("nakhoda:GServiceAccount", name, {}, opts);
        const sa = new gcp.serviceAccount.Account(
            name,
            {
                accountId: name
            },
            { parent: this }
        );
        this.account = sa;

        args.roles.map(
            r =>
                new gcp.projects.IAMMember(
                    `${name}:${r}`,
                    {
                        member: pulumi.interpolate`serviceAccount:${sa.email}`,
                        project: "nk-gke01-london",
                        role: r
                    },
                    { parent: this }
                )
        );
        this.registerOutputs({
            account: this.account
        });
    }
}
```

The serviceAccount exists in GKE, so I am not sure why it fails, maybe it's an issue with the npm packages or it's that it cannot find it?

- Checked the official docs
- Checked on google for similar issues and could not find anything
- Verified that the SA it's there and working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in one of the old **CHANGELOGS** from Pulumi:

```
* Upgrade to pulumi-terraform-bridge v2.6.0.
--
280 | **PLEASE NOTE**
281 | There is a *breaking change* in the `serviceAccount` module name:
282 | * Go `serviceAccount` is now `serviceaccount`
283 | * NodeJS `serviceAccount` is now `serviceaccount`
284 | * Python `service_account` is now `serviceaccount`
```

Changed from `serviceAccount` to `serviceaccount` and now it works.